# InvalidPathException when browsing to "Desktop" in JFileChooser with custom FileFilter on Windows

Tags: java, kotlin, swing

JDK 17.0.3 - Azul Zulu

I have a custom FileFilter class which extends the java classes of `javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter` and `java.io.FileFilter`. (All code is in Kotlin)

The `accept()` method is overridden and overloaded with these two functions:

```
class MyCustomFileFilter(
    /* Irrelevant constructor parameters */
    private val predicate: (path: Path) -> Boolean, // function to pass to the constructor
) : SwingFileFilter(), FileFilter {

    fun accept(path: Path): Boolean {
        return path.isDirectory() || predicate(path)
    }

    override fun accept(file: File): Boolean = accept(file.toPath())
}
```

And the `JFileChooser` is instantiated with an instance of my `FileFilter` class.

```
private val fileChooser = JFileChooser(HomeLocation.currentValue.toFile()).apply {
    isMultiSelectionEnabled = true
    fileFilter = some.object.path.to.filter // filter is an instance of MyCustomFileFilter
}
```

When navigating to the "Desktop" in the file chooser (Windows 10), this error is thrown:

```
Exception in thread "Basic L&F File Loading Thread" java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 0: ::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize(WindowsPathParser.java:182)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:153)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:77)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(WindowsPath.java:92)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(WindowsFileSystem.java:232)
    at java.base/java.io.File.toPath(File.java:2387)
    at fully.qualified.classname.of.MyCustomFileFilter.accept(MyCustomFileFilter.kt:43)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JFileChooser.accept(JFileChooser.java:1654)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicDirectoryModel$FilesLoader.run0(BasicDirectoryModel.java:319)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicDirectoryModel$FilesLoader.run(BasicDirectoryModel.java:295)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

After some debugging, it appears that the file chooser, when browsing the Desktop folder and deciding which files should appear based on the filter, is giving the file object of the "This PC" folder to the accept method. My implementation calls `toPath()` on the `File` and that is when the error happens, because apprently the path string resolves to `::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}`.

Am I doing something wrong or in bad practice by using the `toPath()` function, or is the implementation broken somewhere? Is this a known issue?

Note: I do have a workaround for this problem (which is to not use the `Paths` library, and stick to files) but I would like to know what is going wrong here and why it is happening, or perhaps if there is an open issue for it somehwere.

Comment: Maybe test with [this?](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#isRegularFile(java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.LinkOption...))